# Block keyboard and mouse input of remote user in Teamviewer session

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, mouse, blocking, teamviewer

I'm using Teamviewer to help my family members with their computer problems. Sometimes they use the mouse and keyboard when I'm in the middle of something important. I don't want to tell them not to do it, instead I want to block their keyboard and mouse input when I'm connected to their machine.

I couldn't find an option to do this in Teamviewer preferences. Does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the computer itself you need to enable it in Extras>Options>Advanced>Advanced settings for connecting to this computer>Full access.

When you are connected to remote computer use Menu Actions - disable remote input

Comment: it doesn't work, it's grayed out

Comment: For anyone using a Mac, it seems it's not supported: https://blog.teamviewer.com/teamviewer10-for-mac/#comment-12282

Answer (score 1):

You do this from the remote computer after you have connected. When using Windows on the remote computer, Click on the "Actions" tab (Gear) at the top of the screen and select "Disable Remote Input".  When remoting in from an Ipad, Click on the "Actions" (wrench) tab at the bottom of the screen and select "Disable Remote Input".  I have not used Teamviewer on a Mac or IPhone so I am not sure of the exact steps. But it still should be under the "Actions" Menu.

Comment: it's grayed out in actions tab.

Answer (score 0):

This is now a paid feature in TeamViewer. When you select the option, you get a pop-up dialogue stating:

---

```
     Higher TeamViewer plan required
```

---

The feature you are using is not included in your TeamViewer plan.

Please upgrade your TeamViewer plan to be able to use this feature. If you want to evaluate this feature, please contact us via <tv_site_link>.

### [ Update ]  [ OK ]

Comment: Please quote and cite your sources